# How to make a login page outside the single page application skeleton

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularJS single page application. It is an admin dashboard. However I do not want anyone to access the dashboard unless he is logged in.

Problem that I am facing is when I create a login template, it is usually part of the admin dashboard, since it is a single page application. However I want the login page to look completely different from the single page application index default view. Same for registration page.

What are ways to make a page different completely from the skeleton of the single page application with angular ?

I am sorry if the question is broad but I am new to angular. I do not care about any code written I just would like to understand a good technique for a sort of thing.

Feel free to send me any articles or documentations that explains similar technique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, what you need to do is the following.

1. Use ui-router to control the navigation (or routing) in your application. Note that ui-router will become native in AngularJS 2, right now you will need to use NPM or Bower to include it in your project.
2. Then use the events it provides to determine if the user needs to logon before accessing the given route. If logon is required you can redirect to the logon page, the redirect back upon successful authentication.

Comment: Thank you. will ui routing allow you to have a login view different from the SPA index.html default view. Meaning not nested like the other views ?

Comment: You'll still be in the SPA, but it will help you manage your applications specific use cases, and disallow unauthorized users to the application pages.

Comment: Here is a link to another library that will help you.  https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth. This one works in conjunction with ui-router.